# Plotting a TChart with time as the X-axis

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have a series of 3,600 values, one every second for an hour. I want to chart them as a single series, using TChart in Delphi 7.

The values should be plotted on the Y-axis. What should I pass to AddXY() as the X-axis value? The count of points?

I want to label the X-axis as MM:SS, how do I do that? What do I need beyond this? ...

```
   Chart1.Series[0].XValues.DateTime := True;
   Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat := 'nn:ss';
```

I have been stuck for a while with this one. Can anyone post some sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not wrong, this is what you want

```
Series1.AddXY(<Pass the data value>, <Pass Your value>, '', clRed);
Series1.AddXY(now,                     1, '', clRed); 
Series1.AddXY(now + ( 1 /(24*60*60)),  2, '', clRed); //After 1 seconds 
Series1.AddXY(now + ( 2 /(24*60*60)),  3, '', clRed);  //After 2 seconds
```

Comment: +1 Yes, that looks like it, although I suspect that Add() might be better for me than AddXY(). Thnaks

Comment: @Leonix: The problem with Add() function is actually you are adding strings but not DateTime, so you dont have Datetime scale on y-axis

Comment: @Loenix: That depends on your requirement. If you want show your data w.r.t. to  time you can use this option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Add function instead of AddXY.

```
Add( 100, FormatDateTime('nn:ss',Now), clRed ); 
Add( 80, FormatDateTime('nn:ss',Now), clRed );
```

Comment: +1 This looks like what I want. I will try it out & get back to you. Thanks

Comment: The problem with Add() function is actually you are adding strings but not DateTime, so you dont have Datetime scale on y-axis

Comment: @Bharat: I think LeonixSolutions wants only labels like 'nn:ss' for X axis.