# create a multiple line chart's series from one table by grouping by date

Tags: delphi, charts, delphi-7

I have a dynamic table from query showed by dbgrid that looked like this

```
code | Name | Date      | Time |Score
1    | Alex | 01-Feb-14 | 0600 |5
1    | Alex | 01-Feb-14 | 0700 |7
1    | Alex | 01-Feb-14 | 0800 |8
1    | Alex | 02-Feb-14 | 0600 |7
1    | Alex | 02-Feb-14 | 0800 |8
1    | Alex | 02-Feb-14 | 0900 |8
1    | Alex | 03-Feb-14 | 0700 |7
1    | Alex | 03-Feb-14 | 0800 |5
1    | Alex | 03-Feb-14 | 0900 |8
```

The inputs for query are `code=1, date1=01-feb-14, date2=03-feb-14`

How can I make a line chart that have multiple series, group by date with xlabel = time and y value = score?
My pseudo code is:

```
for date1 to date 2
chart1.addseries
  for time=lowesttime to highesttime do
  begin
  series.xlabel = time
  series.yvalue = score
  end
```

it will look something like this
[image: chart sample]

Comment: thx Sir Rufo for the picture, anyway this is my 1st question, if i need to give more data or else please tell me. 
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate, [`Plotting a TChart with time as the X-axis`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4791053/576719).

Comment: i'm not really want the system time for the label, the time i meant was the time that recorded in my table. plus i need to make it a new series everytime the date change,
but i'm sorry if i asked the wrong question.

Comment: Just replace the x-value with your table time (as a TDateTime value), and define how your x-axis should be displayed. `Chart1.Series[dateX].XValues.DateTime := True;
   Chart1.BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat := 'hh:nn';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create series for each date manually. So you should iterate your dataset, each time when you meet new date you should create new series, add it to the chart, and add values.

In case your dataset is not sorted you might use temporary Dictionary (`TDcitionary<integer, TLineSeries>` from `Generics.Collections`)to store series references.

DateTime value actually is a `double` where int part represents day. So you have own key for each date. Also you can assign it series `Tag` property for possible further use.

Use `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods before and after populating series values.
When you create series use Chart reference as an owner. Next time you clear all series in chart, they will sucesfully destroyed.

Here is an example code:

```
procedure TForm7.UpdateSeries();
var sd : TDictionary<integer, TLineSeries>;
    s : TLineSeries;
    d : TDate;
    dInt : integer;
    x : double;
    xlabel : string;
    i : integer;
begin
    DataChart.SeriesList.Clear();

    sd := TDictionary<integer, TLineSeries>.Create();
    try
        while not query.eof do begin
            d := query.FieldByName('Date').AsDateTime;
            dInt := round(d);

            if not sd.ContainsKey(dInt) then begin
                s := TLineSeries.Create(DataChart);
                s.Tag := dInt;  {for further use}
                DataChart.AddSeries(s);
                s.ParentChart := DataChart;
                s.Title := DateToStr(query.FieldByName('date').AsDateTime);
                s.Color := Random($FFFFFF);

                s.BeginUpdate();

                sd.AddOrSetValue(dInt, s);
            end
            else s := sd[dInt];

            //x value and label
            x := query.FieldByName('time').AsDateTime;
            xlabel := Format('Label %f', [x]);

            s.AddXY(x, query.FieldByName('score').AsInteger, xlabel);

            query.Next();
        end;
    finally
        for i := 0 to DataChart.SeriesCount - 1 do begin
            DataChart.Series[i].EndUpdate();
        end;

        sd.Free();
    end;
end;
```

as question targets `Delphi-7`, it does not know about `generics`. So in this case the easiest way is to sort dataset by date (`ORDER BY date`). And then each time you meet new date, you should create new series. At first you need to initialize `dInt := 0`, and then compare it to `FieldByName('date')`. If it has changed, you should create new series.

```
    dInt := 0;
    try
        while not query.eof do begin
            d := query.FieldByName('Date').AsDateTime;
            if round(d) <> dInt then begin
                dInt := round(d);
                s := TLineSeries.Create(DataChart);
                ....
```

Comment: You don't need a dictionary, if the list is already sorted by group key first `ORDER BY Date, Time`. A new series is needed, if the group key changes

Comment: @SirRufo yes, thats why I wrote "if your dataset is not sorted"

Comment: Oh, I was just focused on the code ... but the question targets **Delphi7** and generics are unknown there

Comment: @SirRufo oh, really, I've missed `delphi-7` tag.

Comment: thanks, i have sort the date and time when i create the sql statement,
still working to make it work, i'll comment again about the result

Comment: thank @teran , just need little modification, somehow command try, s.beginupdate, finally, s.endupdate not working,
God bless you.